# xtext: autoimport and -validate current package

Tags: xtext

I have two connected problems that I kind of know how to solve "by foot" (using custom validators and scope providers). But I'm surprised they don't work out of the box in xtext so I'll ask anyway (in case I missed something).

I have this DSL:

```
Model:
    'package' name=QualifiedName
    imports+=Import*
    entities+=Entity*;

Import:
    'import' importedNamespace=QualifiedName;

Entity:
    name=ID '{'
    references += Reference*
    '}';

Reference:
    name=ID':'entitiy=[Entity]
;

QualifiedName:
    ID('.'ID)*
;
```

Apart from defining multiple entities in the same file I want to be able to define multiple files that "live" in the same package. And I have 2 problems here:

1) I found no obvious way to easily auto-import all elements from the current package. So If I have one file

```
package com.test

EntityA {}
```

and a second one

```
package com.test

import com.test.EntityA // fails if I remove this line

EntityB{
  refToA:EntityA        // I could make qualified names work here.
                        // But that is not the goal.
}
```

the reference to `EntityA` can't be resolved unless I explicitly import it (which is something that I want to avoid) although they are in the same namespace.

So: is there a way to easily enable outimports for the "current" package?

2) I have enabled the `org.eclipse.xtext.validation.NamesAreUniqueValidator` which works fine for entities defined in the same file. But if I redefine an imported entity like this

```
package com.test

import com.test.EntityA

EntityB{
  refToA:EntityA
}

EntityA {}
```

I don't get the expected validation error. Is there something I can do about that without having to write my own validator?

Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make auto-imports work, you need to use Xbase and

```
Model:
    'package' name=QualifiedName
    importSection=XImportSection?
```

To use Xbase, append this to your grammar: `with org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.Xbase`

See http://www.lorenzobettini.it/2013/01/the_ximportsection_in_xbase_2_4/ for details.

The second one can only be solved with your own validator AFAIK. The reason is that you can have a grammar which allows:

```
import com.test.EntityA as X

private EntityA extends X {}
```

Comment: Hi Aaron. Thank you very much for your answer. Your solution for the first part kind of works but is not what I hoped for: I am now able to reference the `Entity` in that specific location with it's qualified name. But I hoped to reference it with `EntityA` (which, as a tried, does not work with your proposal). I'll try to make that more clear in my question.

Comment: Your answer for the second part makes sense though.

Comment: Which version of Xtext?

Comment: You're right with the first part. I checked again and you have to use Xbase and `importSection=XImportSection?`

Comment: Hi Aaron. Thanks again. I tested it with XImportSection. It's still not really what I want. Now I get autocompletion on the referenced entity but still need to use a qualified name (or an import). Guess this is as good as it gets. I'll accept your answer and post my custom scope provider/validator as soon as I really need/write it.